# How to add border in custom imageview?

Tags: android, imageview, paint

I am working with android.I had created an android app with a custom image view which clip corners of the image. here is my custom image view

```
public class CustomImage extends ImageView {

    public static float radius = 18.0f;  

    public CustomImage(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomImage(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomImage(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            CustomImage.this.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        }

        Path clipPath = new Path();
        RectF rect = new RectF(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
        clipPath.addRoundRect(rect, radius, radius, Path.Direction.CW);
        canvas.clipPath(clipPath);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

it works perfect.But I need to add a border around the clipped Image view .How can I do this?

Comment: When I post a question there are lots of people to edit it, but no one ready to help me with post answers :(

Comment: use Canvas.drawRoundRect

Answer (score 0):

If you want rounded conners you can use this library [RoundedImageView](https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView). You can see the code of library for you can implementation.

Or This tutorial [Round Corners](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/pro-tip-round-corners-on-an-android-imageview-with-this-hack/)